# How to delete "/private/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db" in Data

Tags: iphone, sms, jailbreak

I break the phone you want to delete /private/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db" record, 
Here is my source:

```
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"delete from message where rowid=4"];//SELECT address,text FROM message where ROWID=4 

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    const char *error;
    int err = sqlite3_prepare_v2 (contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, &error);
    if (err != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //NSAssert1(0, @"Error updating tables: %s", erroMsg);
     }
}
```

and return "err=1" ,rowid=4 is exist record,"SELECT address,text FROM message where ROWID=4" is right.

please ,help me ,thx

Comment: If this is for a jailbroken phone, you should add that tag.

Answer (score 1):

1. delete a trigger in database.
2. delete the message
3. create the delete